# Replace an image with another when a different image is hovered on

Tags: javascript, html, image-replacement

I am a total noob, so please go easy.

I am trying to replace one image with a second image while hovering on a different element. My problem is that only the first image is being replaced by the link images. I've give each image an ID, I just am not sure how to apply it.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

Here is what I have so far:

Script:

```
<script>

function changeimage(towhat,url){
if (document.images){
document.images.targetimage.src=towhat.src
gotolink=url
}
}
function warp(){
window.location=gotolink
}

</script>
<script language="JavaScript1.1">
var myimages=new Array()
var gotolink="#"

function preloadimages(){
for (i=0;i<preloadimages.arguments.length;i++){
myimages[i]=new Image()
myimages[i].src=preloadimages.arguments[i]
}
}


preloadimages("http://www.dxmgp.com/group/images/color_si.jpg", "http://www.dxmgp.com/group/images/bw_si.jpg","http://www.dxmgp.com/group/images/color_dxm.jpg", "http://www.dxmgp.com/group/images/bw_dxm.jpg","http://www.dxmgp.com/group/images/color_tsg.jpg", "http://www.dxmgp.com/group/images/bw_tsg.jpg","http://www.dxmgp.com/group/images/color_image.jpg", "http://www.dxmgp.com/group/images/bw_image.jpg")
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="upper">
        <div class="u-top">
            <a href="javascript:warp()"><img src="http://www.dxmgp.com/group/images/bw_si.jpg" name="targetimage" id="si" border="0" /></a>
            <a href="javascript:warp()"><img class="picright" src="http://www.dxmgp.com/group/images/bw_dxm.jpg" name="targetimage" id="dxm" border="0" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="u-mid">
            <img src="http://www.dxmgp.com/group/images/bw_owners.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="u-low">
            <a href="javascript:warp()"><img class="picleft" src="http://www.dxmgp.com/group/images/bw_tsg.jpg" id="tsg" /></a>
            <a href="http://www.dxmgp.com" onMouseover="changeimage(myimages[2],this.href)" onMouseout="changeimage(myimages[3],this.href)"><img class="dxmlogo" src="http://www.dxmgp.com/group/images/logo_dxm.png"  /></a>
            <a href="javascript:warp()"><img class="picright" src="http://www.dxmgp.com/group/images/bw_image.jpg" id="img" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="lower">
        <div class="dots"><img src="http://www.dxmgp.com/group/images/topdots.png"></div>
        <div class="logos">
            <a href="http://www.thescoutguide.com">
            <img class="picll" src="http://www.dxmgp.com/group/images/logo_tsg.png"></a>
            <a href="http://www.spatialinsights.com" onMouseover="changeimage(myimages[0],this.href)" onMouseout="changeimage(myimages[1],this.href)"><img class="picmid" src="http://www.dxmgp.com/group/images/logo_si.png"></a>
            <a href="http://www.imagebydxm.com">
            <img class="piclr" src="http://www.dxmgp.com/group/images/logo_image.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="dots"><img src="http://www.dxmgp.com/group/images/lowdots.png"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is `document.images`? What is `document.images.targetimage`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this? Consider you have a `div` containing `image1.png`. When you mouse over a hyperlink, you want to replace `image1.png` with `image2.png`. Then, when you move your mouse away from the hyperlink, `image2.png` will once again be replaced with `image1.png`:

This is your `div` containing the image:

```
<div id="image">
<img src="image1.png" />
</div>
```

This is the hyperlink:

```
<a href="#" onmouseover="mouseOver()" onmouseout="mouseOut()">Mouse over to change image</a>
```

Here are the JavaScript functions that will replace the inner HTML of the `div` with different images:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function mouseOver() {
    document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = '<img src="image2.png" />';
}
function mouseOut() {
    document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = '<img src="image1.png" />';
}
</script>
```

Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, @goddfree, but that seems to only work on the last element on the page. I'd like to for each image to be swapped out by another whenever each link is rolled over. Is it possible to assign the same image id to each specific link, has a variable rollover image rather than than same image being repeated?

Comment: That worked perfectly! I just had to read another tutorial and correctly identify each function:

`function mouseOver1() {
    document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = '<img src="image2.png" />';
}
function mouseOut1() {
    document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = '<img src="image1.png" />';
}function mouseOver2() {
    document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = '<img src="image3.png" />';
}
function mouseOut2() {
    document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = '<img src="image4.png" />';
}`

etc.

Thank you!